# What index the i-th element of any array refer to in c?

Tags: arrays, c, string, indexing

i've stumbled upon an assignment in a piece of code, in which we add a null character to an array `line[i] = '\0'` to explicitly declare it's a string, the latter rose in me the question: as the null character is exactly at the end of any string, well how do we know that adding `\0` to the i-th element of `line` would be added to the last position in it, in my eyes `i` in `line`, could be any element with any index ,so do the i-th index of any array refer to the last position or what ?

Comment: `char line[40];` ... `line` can hold a string **up to** 39 characters long ... `line[0] = 'A'; line[1] = 0;` ... right now, `line` has a 1-char string ... `line[1] = 'B'; line[2] = 'C'; line[3] = 0;` ... and now it has a 3-char string .... `line[1] = 0;` ... and it's back to a 1-char string now. There is no rule we must use all of the 40 bytes.

Comment: @pmg Technically it can up to 40, but 39 is upper limit to be valid string as per C standard, since you need NULL termination on last 40th position, that has index 39.

Comment: Because the human (programmer), writing the program knows where he wants to place the null character.  It comes from the logic of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like this usually appears just after code that has used the same index variable `i` to construct the string.

For example:

```
char string[10];
int i = 0;
string[i++] = 'a';
string[i++] = 'b';
string[i++] = 'c';

string[i] = '\0';
```

Or, more realistically:

```
char line[100];
int i = 0;
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    line[i++] = c;

line[i] = '\0';
```

This second example reads one line of text from standard input and stores it in the `line` array as a proper, null-terminated string.

(In real code, of course, you also have to worry about the possibility of overflowing the array.)

---

To make things really clear, you can imagine writing code like this more explicitly, with a separate variable to hold the length of the string.  For example:

```
i = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    line[i++] = c;

int length_of_string = i;

line[length_of_string] = '\0';
```

When you see that line

```
line[length_of_string] = '\0';
```

it makes it more obvious that the `\0` terminator is being stored at a spot in the string that someone has actually determined to be the length of the string.  But as you can see, since the variable `length_of_string` has just been set based on the value of `i` after the loop, it's perfectly equivalent to just write

```
line[i] = '\0';
```

---

There's sort of an academic-sounding term called [*loop invariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant), but code like this ends up being a perfect example of what it means, and it's worth thinking about for a moment.  A loop invariant is something you can say about a loop that's true at all times, for every trip through the loop, at the beginning or the end or in the middle of the loop.  For the read-a-line loop I've just shown, the loop invariant is:

> `i` always contains the number of characters that have been read into the string `line`.

Let's look at all of the ways this "loop invariant" is true.  To make things very clear, I'm going to write the loop again, with some comments to make it clear what I mean by the "top" and "bottom" of the loop:

```
i = 0;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    /* top of loop */
    line[i++] = c;
    /* bottom of loop */
}
```

1. Before the loop runs, the string is empty, so `i` starts out as 0.
2. At the top of the loop, before the `line[i++] = c` step, `i` still has the value it did last time through the loop.
3. In the middle of the loop, the line `line[i++] = c` simultaneously stores the character `c` into the `line` array (and at the right spot!), and increments `i`.
4. At the bottom of the loop, after the `line[i++] = c` step, `i` contains the updated number of characters in the string.
5. After the loop (and this was your question), since `i` still contains the number of characters that have been read and stored into `line`, it's precisely the right index to use to null-terminate the string, with the line `line[i] = '\0'`.

The other thing that's worth paying attention to here is that the line in the middle of the loop, that simultaneously stores the next character into the `line` array, at the right spot, and increments `i` at the same time, is, once again:

```
line[i++] = c;
```

My question for you to think about is, what if I had instead written

```
line[++i] = c;     /* WRONG */
```

It can be hard, at first, to really understand the difference between `i++` and `++i`, to understand why you would care, to understand why you might pick one over the other.  This code here, I think, is an example that really makes the point.

(For extra credit, think about this: What if arrays in C were 1-based, instead of 0-based?  What parts of the read-one-line loop would change, and is it still possible to maintain all facets of the loop invariant?)

Comment: yeah , thinking about it in the framework of  loop invariant makes it clear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have an already existing string and you just want it to be terminated with \0 on the last+1 index with a correct value, write a function to determine this position. E.g. check the char on the current position and check if the next position contains a legit value. You can then go trough the whole string and determine the last position, then return a pointer to the last position+1 and set your terminator. If you work with a variety of predefined strings this would be the most scalable approach for me.